# Unable to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install Jenkins on my Ubuntu EC2 instance and I performed the following steps to install but couldn't install it.

```
$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
$wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
$sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
$sudo apt update   <--------- (Here I am getting below error)

root@ip-172-31-44-187:~# sudo apt update
```

> Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease
> Err:2 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release
> Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in
> the certificate verification. [IP: 151.101.154.133 443]
> Hit:3 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Get:4 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
> Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
> Get:6 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
> Reading package lists... Done
> E: The repository 'http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' does not have a Release file.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah , I had same problem with this from yesterday , I think this is after yesterday's new update in jenkins 2.303.2 Lts .

Just do ,
apt upgrade ,
apt update,
apt get install jenkins -y .

It worked for me .

Comment: Hey @CrackedEngineer These steps has resolved my issue but instead of apt upgrade there should be exact packages names which needs to be updated.

Using upgrade will update all the installed packages on the systems and which can cause trouble to the applications to run.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Yeah i agree with you @DineshS . If you find any break through , make time to post it ,so it will be pretty helpful .

Answer (score 27):

Instead of upgrading every package with apt-get upgrade, I used:
`sudo apt install ca-certificates`

And then:
`sudo apt-get update` worked just fine.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted. This worked for me and might work for other people having the same problem. The accepted answer of `apt upgrade` is only helpful if you're okay with upgrading all your packages, and it turned out that was unnecessary for me.

Answer (score 13):

I was facing same issue when I tried to install jenkins in AWS ec2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04). Below steps helped me.

1. Update Ubuntu packages and all installed applications

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

2. Next, Install JDK

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
```

3. Verify Java version

```
java -version
```

4. Add gpg key for jenkins installation

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -
```

5. Add the repository address to our /etc/apt/sources.list.d file

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
e>     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
```

6. Update our package list again

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

7. Install Jenkins

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

It worked like charm!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with adding Jenkins repository on Ubuntu 18.04

> **add-apt-repository  'deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/'**

`Ign:5 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease                                                           Err:6 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release                                                          Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 199.232.66.133 443] Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         Reading package lists... Done E: The repository 'https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

For fixing this issue you need to **install/update ca-certificates**

> **sudo apt install ca-certificates**

After that, you can successfully add the Jenkins repository

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to highlight anything new

Comment: HI, @NicoHaase I just want to highlight that updating ca-certificates fixed the problem and add an additional description because similar answers have a minus score which made them less attractive. In my case, I didn't want to update other packages.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 3):

Since March 28,2023 Jenkins weekly release using new repository signing keys. Below mentioned commands help me to resolve this issue.

```
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | 
sudo tee \ /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to correct the first answer provided. You need to run apt install Jenkins -y instead of apt get install jenkins -y. Running the below commands will fix your error. If you are not using root ensure that you add sudo before of all the below commands.

```
apt upgrade 

apt update

apt install jenkins -y
```

You will find out your jenkins is started using the below command.

```
service jenkins status
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Whatever answer you refer to: what was wrong with it? What did you change?

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

As it might help some, none of the above solutions worked for me, but it was a silly mistake! *Please* read ALL the outputs. In my case, I'd missed an error a few lines above which indicated that I didn't have "curl" installed (!) on my Debian server. And so copy pasting the key installation lines from the Jenkins manual (which uses curl) didn't succeed, so all those unsecure errors in result.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of upgrading every package with the apt-get upgrade, I used: `sudo apt install ca-certificates`
And then: `sudo apt-get` update worked just fine

Comment: Did you just copy an other answer?!

Comment: Please share more details - copying the command from another answer might be fine if you add an explanation

Answer (score -3):

Please Follow these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -
```

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
e>     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, how is this answer different from the others which are already posted here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).